# How to do access windows paste functionality just like teracopy does?

Tags: windows, copy, clipboard, paste, clip

I am trying to copy a set of files or say set of folder (files can be of higher size or of any type), when i try to copy then everything is stored in clipboard, i want to know how to access the details from clipboard?
Also, how to access the paste functionality of windows? I mean i want to do something while something is getting pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shell clipboard formats from MSDN.  They're documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx

In particular, CF_HDROP is really just a text representation of the list of file paths that were copied. Get it into a string buffer and you will have all of those path names.

The answer to this question will give you the correct approach. It's Delphi, but it's very readable: [How do I check whether I've successfully fetched a list of file names from the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011609/how-do-i-check-whether-ive-successfully-fetched-a-list-of-file-names-from-the-c)